# Why isnt this counter class "thread safe"

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Im trying to figure out why this isnt "thread safe" and im drawing blanks public

```
public class Counter {
private static int val = 0;

public Counter() {
}

public static void set(int newVal) {
    val = newVal;
}

public static void decrement() {
    int tmp = val;

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100L);
    } catch (Exception var2) {
        ;
    }

    --tmp;
    val = tmp;
}

public static boolean depleted() {
    return val == 0;
}
}
```

Is it because if many Counters are made, it will not work correctly? Say for example a bunch of characters using Counter to make a move. If a character is out of moves to make then a new character starts making moves. Will all characters implementing Counter not allow Counter to work correctly? How does it relate to being thread safe?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what thread-safety is... Have a read-through ***[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)***.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because if many Counters are made, it will not work correctly?

No.  That's not what thread-safety means.

Suppose that some program `P` can be said to be *correct* if it **always** satisfies a set of conditions `C`.  Thread safety means that if the program `P` is correct with one thread, it is also correct with more than one thread.  A more detailed explanation may be found in the Wikipedia article on [thread safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

In this example, the code is *by design* intended to implement a single counter that will be shared by the entire application.  If that is not what is needed, it is a problem.  However, the problem is with the code not being correct according to the implied requirements (for multiple counters) not with thread safety.

There are thread-safety concerns with this code.  Specifically, if two or more threads used this class, then the code would not work properly ... as a single shared counter.  For example, on thread might not see the updates made by the other, or decrements could be lost.  The problem is that the threads would be using a shared variable (i.e. `val`) without proper synchronization.  If there is no synchronization, then you can get *race conditions* and *memory anomalies*.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. For further understanding, im trying to implement this to see exactly how if two threads used this, then it wouldnt work properly. What are some simple implementations I can do to see it in action, and prove its not thread safe?

Comment: Get rid of the `sleep` calls, then just write a multi-threaded application that does lots of operations quickly from multiple threads ... and look for anomalous answers.  If you get anomalies you have (probably) proven that it is not thread-safe.  (But if you don't see anomalies you have NOT proven the code to be thread-safe!!)

Comment: Proving code is thread-safe is difficult.  It requires a detailed analysis of the code, and a deep understanding of the Java Memory Model (JMM).